# How to find window restore in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

How to find the window state using javascript.Consider our application need to `alert('restor')` when browser unmaximize and also need to `alert('maximized')` when restore or maximize the browser.Can anybody please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to specifically detect maximize/restore events. The closest you can get is the [`onresize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onresize) event which tells you that the window has been resized. You could use this in conjunction with `screen.width` and `screen.height` to possibly guess if the window is maximized.